# LINQ non-linear order by string length

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a list of string ordered such that the longest are on either end of the list and the shortest are in the middle.  For example:

```
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
EEEEE
FFFFFF
```

would get sorted as:

```
FFFFFF
DDDD
BB
A
CCC
EEEEE
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, I was specifically looking for a LINQ implementation to achieve the desired results because I wasn't sure how/if it was possible to do using LINQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't ask how and why... ^^

```
list.Sort(); // In case the list is not already sorted.

var length = list.Count;

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, length)
                       .Select(i => length - 1 - 2 * i)
                       .Select(i => list[Math.Abs(i - (i >> 31))])
                       .ToList();
```

Okay, before I forget how it works, here you go.

A list with 6 items for example has to be reordered to this; the longest string is at index 5, the shortest one at index 0 of the presorted list.

```
5 3 1 0 2 4
```

We start with `Enumerable.Range(0, length)` yielding

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

then we apply `i => length - 1 - 2 * i` yielding

```
5 3 1 -1 -3 -5
```

and we have the non-negative part correct. Now note that `i >> 31` is an arithmetic left shift and will copy the sign bit into all bits. Therefore non-negative numbers yield 0 while negative numbers yield -1. That in turn means subtracting `i >> 31` will not change non-negative numbers but add 1 to negative numbers yielding

```
5 3 1 0 -2 -4
```

and now we finally apply `Math.Abs()` and get

```
5 3 1 0 2 4
```

which is the desired result. It works similarly for lists of odd length.

Comment: But nothing you want to put into production code. Or maybe only with a *lot* of comments.

Answer (score 10):

You could create two ordered groups, then order the first group descending(already done) and the second group ascending:

```
var strings = new List<string> { 
        "A",
        "BB",
        "CCC",
        "DDDD",
        "EEEEE",
        "FFFFFF"};
var two = strings.OrderByDescending(str => str.Length)
        .Select((str, index) => new { str, index })
        .GroupBy(x => x.index % 2)
        .ToList(); // two groups, ToList to prevent double execution in following query
List<string> ordered = two.First() 
    .Concat(two.Last().OrderBy(x => x.str.Length))
    .Select(x => x.str)
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
[0] "FFFFFF"    string
[1] "DDDD"      string
[2] "BB"        string
[3] "A"         string
[4] "CCC"       string
[5] "EEEEE"     string
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option, which I find more readable and easy to follow:
You have an ordered list:

```
var strings = new List<string> { 
        "A",
        "BB",
        "CCC",
        "DDDD",
        "EEEEE",
        "FFFFFF"};
```

Create a new list and simply alternate where you add items::

```
var new_list = new List<string>();  // This will hold your results
bool start = true;                  // Insert at head or tail

foreach (var s in strings)
{
    if (start)
        new_list.Insert(0,s);
    else        
        new_list.Add(s);

    start = !start;             // Flip the insert location
}
```

Sweet and simple :)

As for **Daniel Bruckner** comment, if you care about which strings comes first, you could also change the start condition to:

```
 // This will make sure the longest strings is first
 bool start= strings.Count()%2 == 1;
```

Comment: This will be kind of off by one for lists of even length - the longest string will be in the last position. Fix: `var start = strings.Count % 2 == 1;`

Comment: He said `longest are on either end of the list `, so still works in my book :). I wanted to avoid calculating where to put the string, and KISS it.

Comment: Fair point. I finally gave up figuring out how I would implement it in production code.

Comment: I wasn't very explicit in my question -- I was specifically asking how to do it using LINQ.  My intention wasn't to get an implementation, but more of a thought exercise of "how would one do this using X".  Thanks for posting though.

Comment: I'd also like to say, I'd probably go this route in production code and avoid any of the strictly-linq solutions I've seen/come up with.  KISS indeed.

Comment: Well ... if you would have said LINQ to begin with, you would have saved me feeling unloved for offering a good solution :) . Back to coding now :)

Comment: @Noctis hey, you deleted [your Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254421/456814) before I could apologize. I'm here to say I'm sorry for my blunt response. You can go ahead and ask your question again, just be careful about how it comes across, users on Meta can be pretty sensitive around controversial topics. Also, be aware that [votes on Meta are complicated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108/456814).